# kafka-connect-jdbc source connector OOM

Tags: docker, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am using kafka-connect-jdbc:5.3.1 and when I am running the connector it kicks me out with Exception: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Thread-11"`

I have tried increasing the heap space to 4gb but still it fails. The EC2 instance type is t2.large and no of records is atmost 4 million.

my property files looks like

```
name=jdbc_source_postgres
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

connection.url=jdbc:postgresql:/localhost:5432/demo?user=********&password=*******&defaultFetchSize=10000&useCursorFetch=true
tasks.max=10
table.types=TABLE
table.whitelist=sample_table
mode=timestamp
timestamp.column.name=last_modified
validate.non.null=false
batch.max.rows=100
topic.prefix=kafka02-
poll.interval.ms=3600
```

I am running this connector through a Docker container on an EC2 and my docker file looks like this

```
version: "3"
services:
  connect:
    image: kafka-connect:latest
    ports:
      - 80:8083
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - .:/src:cached
    environment:
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java"
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-5.3.0.jar
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: "connect"
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: connect-status
      CONNECT_KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: "-Xms256M -Xmx8G"
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: localhost:9092
    command: connect-standalone /src/connect-standalone.properties /src/connectors/kafka-source.properties
```

I have tried each and every possibility with the configuration tweaking but yet failed. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property isn't `CONNECT_KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS`. It's just `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS`

Note that a t2.large has a max of 8 GB itself, and you need overhead for the OS, so you wouldn't be able to assign 8GB purely to the Java process running in the container anyway

Sidenote, it'd be recommended not to override the command to be connect standalone, and rather let the tasks be distributed amongst a cluster of Connect workers, when possible